# How to filter and transform this collection using JavaScript ES6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter

I have a query function that outputs a collection of elements, having a simplified structure like so:

```js
var obj = [
  {
    body: [
      {
        prop1: 2,
        prop2: 17,
        // ...more props,
        date: '2020-08-30',
      },
      {
        prop1: 2,
        prop2: 1,
        // ...more props,
        date: '2020-08-29',
      },
      // ...
    ],
    // ...additional elements,
    slug: 'Bay'
  },
  // ...
]
```

How can I efficiently filter and transform this result object using only JavaScript code or ES6 functions wherein the value of `date` nested inside the `body` array is **today** and the additional elements are **excluded**?

Here is my expected outcome:

```js
var obj = [
 {
   prop1: 2,
   prop2: 17,
   // ...more props,
   date: '2020-08-30',
   slug: 'Bay'
 },
 // ...
]
```

---

**EDIT**: To be clear,

1. The object inside the `body` array matching the condition (`date` is today) should be merged to the parent object.
2. The structure guarantees that there would be no repeated properties. Only at most one object exists inside the `body` array per `date`.
3. `slug`, `prop1`, `prop2`, etc. are all unique indices and shouldn't cause repeated property problems as well.
4. The `body` array in each object and the collection itself would be quite large, so I'd appreciate it a lot if the solution would be *efficient.*

And it should also be clear that if the `date` today doesn't match any objects inside the `body` array, it should **skip** the parent object.

For example:

```js
var obj = [
  { // Object 1
    body: [
      {
        prop1: 2,
        prop2: 17,
        // ...more props,
        date: '2020-08-30',
      }
    ],
    // ...additional elements,
    slug: 'Bay'
  },
  { // Object 2
    body: [
      {
        prop1: 2,
        prop2: 1,
        // ...more props,
        date: '2020-08-29',
      }
    ],
    // ...additional elements,
    slug: 'Mino'
  }
]
```

The expected outcome would be:

```js
var obj = [
 { // Object 1
   prop1: 2,
   prop2: 17,
   // ...more props,
   date: '2020-08-30',
   slug: 'Bay'
 }
]
```

Comment: what happened to the `body` array in the expected outcome (why has it disappeared)? Are the objects inside `body` merged into the parent object? If so, what happens with repeated properties?

Comment: Do you know why you want ES6?

Comment: @NickParsons Yes, the `body` array should be merged into the parent object, and the structure guarantees that there would be no repeated properties. To be specific, only one element will exist for each `date`

Comment: @evolutionxbox I am still learning JavaScript, and I guessed using ES6 for object/array manipulations would make it *efficient.*

Comment: @D.B. so basically there would only be at most one object which has the date of the current day? (or  is it possible that there are more and `prop1`, `prop2` are called different things)

Comment: @D.B. Will *exactly one*  element exist for the current date, or at most one?

Comment: @NickParsons Yes, only at most one object per `date` and the `prop1`, `prop2`, etc. are unique indices too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will provide the desired result

```
var today = "2020-08-30";
var resultObj = [];
var obj = [
  {
    body: [
      {
        prop1: 2,
        prop2: 17,
        // ...more props,
        date: '2020-08-30',
      },
      {
        prop1: 2,
        prop2: 1,
        // ...more props,
        date: '2020-08-29',
      },
      // ...
    ],
    // ...additional elements,
    slug: 'Bay'
  },
  // ...
]

for(var objData of obj) {
    for(var bodyData of objData.body) {
        if(bodyData.date == today) {
            bodyData.slug = objData.slug;
            resultObj.push(bodyData);
        }
    }
}
console.log(resultObj)
```